# Getting "file does not exist" error when running an Amazon EMR job 

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, emr

I have uploaded my data 
genotype1_large_ind_large.txt 
phenotype1_large_ind_large_1.txt

to the S3 system, and in the EMR UI, I set the parameter like below

RunDear.run s3n://scalability/genotype1_large_ind_large.txt s3n://scalability/phenotype1_large_ind_large_1.txt s3n://scalability/output_1phe 33 10 4

In my class RunDear.run I will distribute the file genotype1_large_ind_large.txt and phenotype1_large_ind_large_1.txt to the cache

However, after running the EMR, I get the following error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /genotype1_large_ind_large.txt

I am wondering why there is slash '/' in front of the file name? 
how to make it work?

I also tried to use like below, but my program will take -cacheFile as an argument, thus also does not work,

RunDear.run -cacheFile s3n://scalability/genotype1_large_ind_large.txt#genotype.txt -cacheFile s3n://scalability/phenotype1_large_ind_large_1.txt#phenotype.txt s3n://scalability/output_1phe 33 280 4

Answer (score 0):

I finally realize it is the problem of using the filesystem, so I add a code in the program like below
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get( URI.create("s3://scalability"), conf);