# Reading file inside main function - Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, emr, amazon-emr, distributed-cache

I am trying to read a file in the main method of my hadoop job. Not in the mapper or reducer.
I am using the EMR Amazon with a CUSTOM JAR

```
The command line is arguments: -files s3://[path]#source.xml
```

Inside the main funcion I am doing:

```
File file = new File("source.xml")
```

I dont know if the distributed cache is available on main function or just in the mapper/reducer functions. Do i need to use DistributedCache API?

the line code that AWS is executing:

```
hadoop jar /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-1YBXTPYJ2YK44/JobTeste_SomenteLeitura.jar -files s3://stoneagebrasil/TesteBVS/sources.xml
```

How can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
Path path = new Path("test.txt");
```

to read file ,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fs.open(path)));
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, i saw that -cacheFile is just for Streaming on EMR. I am using Custom Jar. So i tried -files s3://[path] and using FileSystem. But now i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hadoop/sources.xml

Comment: I saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315378/getting-file-does-not-exist-error-when-running-an-amazon-emr-job. I am tring this solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Until now what i found that is impossible to read a file in distributed cache inside the hadoop driver (main function). It is because the file is goind to be distributed (copied to slave nodes) after i start the job.

The solution was read the file directly from S3.